# Training my chatbot

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, chatbot

I am currently working on ChatterBot in Python. And while doing that I got stuck in how to train my model. Since I have a long list of faq's to feed in my bot, so can anyone help me giving a right code on how I can train my model with writing each question and answer manually.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at sequence prediction also known as 'sequence to sequence learning'.   Google's TensorFlow has an implementation of this model called ['seq2seq'](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/).  Suriyadeepan Ram wrote a good article, with code, entitled ["Chatbots with Seq2Seq"](http://suriyadeepan.github.io/2016-06-28-easy-seq2seq/) which should help you get started.